# Is there an in-universe explanation for the change in primary weapon of SG1?

Tags: stargate, stargate-sg1

Members of SG1 are shown to carry a H&K MP5 as their primary weapon in the earlier series/seasons. At some point, they replace that with an FN P-90.

Was it ever explained why?

Comment: Out of universe it was almost certainly down to the availability of blank-firing rounds. I've also seen rumours that the show was getting product-placement money from H&K for the first few seasons but that's totally unconfirmed.

Comment: Plus the empty rounds drop to the floor and are not spat sidewards on your co-actors glasses.

Comment: FWIW, the change happened after _"The First Ones"_.

Comment: Mallozzi said that he liked to have an odd variety of weapons to emphasise that they're a 'special ops' team that can be trusted to choose their own guns.

Comment: I could've sworn there was a line or two about the new equipment being issued when they change over.

Comment: @BrianS: O'Neill: "I recommend units one and two, P90s", ~5mins into "_The First Ones_". That's the best I can find.

Comment: Interestingly, the move over to custom weapons was for [much the same reason](http://dianekateri.freeservers.com/stargate/articles/majorresource.htm); “*We normally use P-90s on our show but since the war [with Iraq] there’s been a shortage of P-90 shells or blanks, so we can’t use that particular gun as much,” explains the actress. “So the props guys have made me what we call a ‘Carter special’, which is, in fact, an amalgamation of three different guns.*"

Comment: You'd think they'd be able to police the brass and have a shop reload blanks. After all, they don't have to have a full charge. They only possible problem would be if reloads tend to jam in the guns.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There is a specific episode when the characters change weapons, and it is explained why they do so. The episode where the switch was made is called [The First Ones](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/The_First_Ones), which is season 4 episode 8. After Daniel gets kidnapped by an Unas, and after the rest of SG-1 figures out that it was an Unas who kidnapped him, they return to Stargate command. Once there, they inform General Hammond that an Unas had taken Daniel, and Jack recommended that they go back with P90s.

Turns out that they work pretty well against bad guys, so from then on the team has used them.

Comment: Unas being particularly hard to kill and all.

Comment: Not really an explanation, though.  The exact dialogue is: "O'NEILL : Recommend units one and two, P-90's. I also recommend we take off right now, Sir."

Answer (score 22):

That is obvious.

FN P-90 has more stopping power and a higher rate of fire than a H&K MP5!
It is also marginally lighter and has a higher effective range.
If you are Special Ops what do you go for??

Portability, Stopping power, rate of fire.
You don't want to get too encumbered, you want the things you are shooting to stay dead and you want to put so much hurt downrange that enemies get suppressed when you fire at them.

A simple Wiki search will tell you all you need to know about these 2 guns.

Never explained why, although if they had any kind of advisor he/she would tell  to switch. Especially if the Director/producer is looking for a more cool looking gun.

Comment: This is more of a real-world answer. We're after an in-universe explanation why they'd change.

Comment: @Richard: This _is also_ an in Universe answer, as the in Universe military is based on the real world military, if real world military would make this choice why wouldn't the in universe military?

Comment: Looks perfectly in-universe reasoning to me. Plus you go from a 30 round clip to a 50 round. Plus keeping with the sci-fi theme, looked more sci-fi.

Comment: Clearly *you* think that it's a superior weapon. The problem is that you've not shown me why Jack O'Neill would agree with you.

Comment: It's a fair real world answer, I'll grant that. If we were using real-world justification then surely they shouldn't have been wearing Blackhawk medic-vests which have no ammunition pouches. +1 for a good answer.

Comment: They do give the p90s to the rebel jaffa at one point and carter teaches them to use them, and while teaching explains why they are such good guns. never any complaints about the mp5, but at least it shows they like the p90s. They also started wearing those dumb eye guards when they got the p90s >.>

Comment: The FN P90 is a superior weapon considering its ability to deliver damage, increase range of fire and its rate of fire. It would have been negligent to continue sending teams out with MP5s once they met the enemy's superior firepower and technology. Field the best gear or don't go.

Comment: @BinaryWorrier This is as much an in-universe answer as answering the question "Is there an in-universe explanation for the different uniforms between star-trek series" with "in 1989 we had better clothing materials". Let me put it this way: If someone was asking for an out-of-universe answer, would this not be a much better fit? The answer isn't bad, since the series doesn't seem to provide justification and this seems to be as close to an explanation as you can get. But it's still incomplete - it does _not_ specify whether an in-universe explanation exists or not.

Comment: @Himarm I understood that more as a general praise of Earth gunpowder-based automatic weapons when compared with the Jaffa Staff weapon, not necessarily as a specific praise of P90s.

Comment: @svick well its literally the only time they brought them up i believe lol. just thought i would throw that in. since it was ontopic.

Comment: I like the P90 but they have jamming issues. Other then that they are better then the MP5.

Comment: They show that the P90 can take out a Jaffa with significantly less shots than the MP5. Although never explicitly stated in words, they consistently show this to be the case, even in later seasons when MP5 or other non-P90 weapons are used. If it was just stylistic, they would not have shown MP5s to be less effective in later seasons. I am guessing they brought back some Jaffa armor to area 51 and tested various weapons against it and changed what they carried accordingly.

Comment: If it's obvious that the P90 is a better choice than the MP5, you're left having to explain why they used the MP5 in the first place.

Comment: Why not? The MP5 is a capable firearm. It would not have been my choice, but there is no reason to use the P90 before they determine that it's superior firepower is necessary. The MP5 would have been the more economical choice. Cheaper firearm and ammunition, while providing defensive capability off world.

Comment: As I read it, the question is less why they chose one gun over another, and more about *why they switched.* This answer does not address that at all. Was the P90 unavailable (in-universe) at the start of the show, so they just switched to the newer gun when it got developed? Or were both originally available, and if so, why wasn't the P90 the *original* choice?

Comment: @KRyan P90 was in use at the time of the show. Might be product placement issue or a license to use P90 in the show too. H&K might have payed the show for the first season or something too.

Comment: @JohnMeacham MP5 uses 9 mill caliber. Same crap as handguns. P90 uses bigger caliber bullets. So testing or no testing P90 has a bigger bullet, higher muzzle velocity and that in itself is enough to kill things faster than a puny 9 mill bullet.

Comment: @cherubel actually, the P90 fires a smaller bullet. It fires the FN 5.7x28mm with a 31 grain bullet. 9x19mm parabellum has a 115 or 124 grain bullet, which is about 4 times the size. But the 5.7 has a much higher muzzle velocity and is designed to pierce armour, unlike the 9mm, and Jaffa are usually armoured. Also, the 5.7 is also used in handguns, specifically, the P90's sidearm companion, the Five-seven.

Comment: @Cherubel Literally the opposite of the truth

Answer (score 9):

No, a rationale for the change in weaponry is not discussed at any point in the script of any episode.  (Hard to provide a reference for a counterfactual, so you'll have to trust my having watched each episode too many times.)

As mentioned above, Jack does discuss the benefits of projectile weapons (specifically the P90) over staff weapons when giving them to the rebel Jaffa, but there's never a discussion of P90 vs. other Earth weapons.

On a side note, over the years SG1 hired several [combat veterans as consultants](http://www.cracked.com/article_21622_5-ways-movies-get-gunfights-wrong-based-experience.html) specifically to improve the realism of their combat scenes.  That's why SG teams are always seen firing in short bursts (even with full-auto weapons) and why the actors often yell to each other during pauses in firefights (because in reality they'd be deaf).  Notice how when they're in Zat/staff fights, they don't yell to each other very much.

Comment: _"SG teams are always seen firing in short bursts"_ Actually it always distressed me that they didn't do this very much

Answer (score 1):

The hypothetical in-universe explanations that I've heard which seem to hold water are

1) The unavailability of their older weapons owing to the start of the Iraq/Afghanistan wars. (It's well established in universe that those wars were taking place)

2) The older weapons were simply being phased out of service for newer ones, and as maintenence parts were harder to find, well, that sort of thing does happen in militaries fairly regularly.

That said, neither of these answers are canon.

Answer (score 0):

There was also a point in which the base had upgraded all the monitors on base from CRTs to LCDs, and yet there was no in-universe explanation for that either.

Hardware upgrades happen on a regular basis because they happen in the real world too. And they happen for the same reason: newer, better equipment comes along. It's not a particularly interesting thing to spend time on, and it doesn't add to the story.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. In this instance, there's no obvious reason for the change from a newer/better argument.